# Saving downloaded pdf-files

Tags: 12.04

downloaded pdf-documents are saved as pdf.html instead of simply pdf and that means that I can read the document only online. I noticed that the Data menu of Ubuntu 12.04 only offers the alternative to save the page instead of the alternative save a copy - that is what I was used to. Is that the problem of the version or settings of Firefox???

Comment: I don't use FF, but in the mean time you should be able to save the file **without** the .html extension, or rename the file after download removing the .html extension...hopefully some learned FF user can answer the question about FF

Comment: @pfeiffep no, removing the extension in this case doesn’t solve the problem. The file is really an HTML one.

Comment: Are there some accessible links (no login or password) that illustrate this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox (I'm using the **version 19**), you should have some kind of PDF reader. Instead of right-clicking and clicking  `Save as`, just click the Download button of that PDF reader.

[image: How to save a PDF document]
(Click the image to see it in full resolution)

Comment: PDF reader was available with version 15.